# How to write in merged cell in Excel using `openpyxl` library?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` library to write in existing Excel file in separate cells.

**How do I write some text in Excel merged cell?**

**ERROR** `AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only`

when cells are merged:

**CODE:**

```
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=src)
        for row in df_short.itertuples():
            ws = wb[row.sheet]
            try:
                cell = 'N'+str(row.id)
                ws[cell] = '=HYPERLINK("%s","#%s")' % (row.txt_path, row.txt)
```

Comment: You may try first unmerging the cells, then setting the value, then merging them back together? https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#merge-unmerge-cells

Comment: Alternatively, try referring to the single top/left-most cell like `ws.cells(row=1, column=1).value = ...` (obviously, replace with the correct row/column values).

Comment: Good idea! Ho to check in advance if particular cell is merged?

Comment: If you always write to the top/left `cell`, I don't think you need to bother checking whether it's merged. But you can see some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574991/how-to-detect-merged-cells-in-excel-with-openpyxl/42823355

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code where ws is the sheet object.

```
    ws.cell(cells).value = 'Whatever you want it to be'
```

replace cells with the top-left cell of the merged block. I usually keep this as rows and columns. So B1 would be represented as row = 1, column = 2.

After the value =

Put any string or integer of what you want to place inside the cell.

Answer (score -2):

I had this exact error and solution for conda environment within python3.5 was

```
conda install -c conda-forge openpyxl=2.5.14 -y
```

Similarly for pip3 environments:

```
pip3 install openpyxl==2.5.14 -y
```